# "add-newipaddress" results in "Windows System Error 1168" and "object not found"

Tags: powershell, networking, windows-server-2016

I installed chocolatey and since then everything went wrong. I can't add any new IP addresses on a netadapter. Since I *really* want to learn the troubleshooting for networking, instead of reinstalling I want a solution for my issue.

```bsh
PS C:\Windows\system32> New-NetIPAddress 192.168.3.2 -prefixlength 24 -InterfaceAlias "Hades Ethernet" -DefaultGateway 192.168.3.1
New-NetIPAddress : Element not found.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-NetIPAddress 192.168.3.2 -prefixlength 24 -InterfaceAlias "Hades  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MSFT_NetIPAddress:ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetIPAddress) [New-NetIPAddress], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 1168,New-NetIPAddress
```

When troubleshooting:

```bsh
PS C:\Windows\system32> get-netadapter | Get-NetIPAddress
Get-NetIPAddress : No matching MSFT_NetIPAddress objects found by CIM query for instances of the ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetIPAddress class on the  CIM server: SELECT * FROM
MSFT_NetIPAddress  WHERE ((InterfaceIndex = 25)) AND ((InterfaceAlias LIKE 'Hades Ethernet')). Verify query parameters and retry.
At line:1 char:18
+ get-netadapter | Get-NetIPAddress
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MSFT_NetIPAddress:String) [Get-NetIPAddress], CimJobException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CmdletizationQuery_NotFound,Get-NetIPAddress


Get-NetIPAddress : No matching MSFT_NetIPAddress objects found by CIM query for instances of the ROOT/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetIPAddress class on the  CIM server: SELECT * FROM
MSFT_NetIPAddress  WHERE ((InterfaceIndex = 28)) AND ((InterfaceAlias LIKE 'VirtualBox Host-Only Network')). Verify query parameters and retry.
At line:1 char:18
+ get-netadapter | Get-NetIPAddress
+                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (MSFT_NetIPAddress:String) [Get-NetIPAddress], CimJobException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CmdletizationQuery_NotFound,Get-NetIPAddress
```

The other adapters are working just fine. Does anyone have a solution or - even better - a documentation on such a case? I can't seem to find anything useful on simv2 regarding this problem.

it is also not listed in get-netipinterface:

```bsh
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-NetIPInterface

ifIndex InterfaceAlias                  AddressFamily NlMtu(Bytes) InterfaceMetric Dhcp     ConnectionState PolicyStore
------- --------------                  ------------- ------------ --------------- ----     --------------- -----------
5       Ethernet 3                      IPv6                  1500              35 Disabled Disconnected    ActiveStore
18      vEthernet (Switch LM)           IPv6                  1500              15 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
7       isatap.{B3B988D0-6CA7-42B5-9... IPv6                  1280              75 Disabled Disconnected    ActiveStore
26      isatap.{5F9C575A-3AA4-431C-A... IPv6                  1280              75 Disabled Disconnected    ActiveStore
11      vEthernet (VirtualBox Host-O... IPv6                  1500              25 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
16      vEthernet (Intel(R) 82574L G... IPv6                  1500              25 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
3       Reusable ISATAP Interface {2... IPv6                  1280              75 Disabled Disconnected    ActiveStore
24      isatap.fritz.box                IPv6                  1280              75 Disabled Disconnected    ActiveStore
8       Ethernet 1                      IPv6                  1500               5 Enabled  Disconnected    ActiveStore
6       isatap.{4002D68C-B8ED-4638-A... IPv6                  1280              75 Disabled Disconnected    ActiveStore
1       Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1     IPv6            4294967295              75 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
5       Ethernet 3                      IPv4                  1500              35 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
18      vEthernet (Switch LM)           IPv4                  1500              15 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
11      vEthernet (VirtualBox Host-O... IPv4                  1500              25 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
16      vEthernet (Intel(R) 82574L G... IPv4                  1500              25 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
8       Ethernet 1                      IPv4                  1500               5 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
1       Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1     IPv4            4294967295              75 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore


PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-NetIPInterface -ifIndex 25
Get-NetIPInterface : No MSFT_NetIPInterface objects found with property 'InterfaceIndex' equal to '25'.  Verify the value of the property and retry.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-NetIPInterface -ifIndex 25
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (25:UInt32) [Get-NetIPInterface], CimJobException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CmdletizationQuery_NotFound_InterfaceIndex,Get-NetIPInterface
```

output of get-netadapter, where Hades Ethernet and Virtual Box are listed:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> get-netadapter

Name                      InterfaceDescription                    ifIndex Status       MacAddress             LinkSpeed
----                      --------------------                    ------- ------       ----------             ---------
Ethernet 1                Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Con...       8 Disconnected 40-A8-F0-CA-D5-F5          0 bps
Management                Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #3          18 Up           00-15-5D-6E-64-0B        10 Gbps
vEthernet (VirtualBox ... Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2          11 Up           0A-00-27-00-00-09         1 Gbps
vEthernet (Intel(R) 82... Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter             16 Up           40-A8-F0-CA-D5-F4         1 Gbps
Ethernet 3                TAP-Windows Adapter V9                        5 Disconnected 00-FF-32-EB-49-EE       100 Mbps
VirtualBox Host-Only N... VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter        28 Up           0A-00-27-00-00-1C         1 Gbps
Hades Ethernet            Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network Conn...      25 Up           40-A8-F0-CA-D5-F4         1 Gbps
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If you're output of `Get-NetIPInterface` is correct, you don't seem to have an interface with the ID of 25 or an adapter with the interface alias "Hades". All the errors you have are because you are referencing a network adapter that doesn't seem to be there. Try adding the unfiltered output of `Get-NetAdapter` to your post. Please use code blocks, it makes it easier for other people to read and help you.

Comment: Hi Ash, thank you very much for your input! I added code blocks as well as the output of get-netadapter where the adapter in question is listed.